# Why is client-side Blazor using .NET Standard 2.0 and how to use .NET Core 3.0 with Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard, blazor, .net-core-3.0

Is it possible to use .NET Core 2.2 or 3.0 with Blazor?

Because at this moment, the `blazorhosted` template creates a client-side project as .NET Standard which prevents using .NET Core 3.0.

> Project blazor.Shared is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Project blazor.Shared supports: netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0) blazor.Client   C:\app\blazor.Client\blazor.Client.csproj   1

After changing everything to .NET Core 3.0, I get the following error:

> rzc generate exited with code 1.

So, is it possible and I'm doing something wrong or is there no way yet?

Comment: Targeting .NET Core is to big for a download in the context of a website. Even for minimal .NET Core applications you need the runtime, which is something like 60-80 MB. Waaaaaaaaaaaayy to much to be downloaded when the user visits the website. Blazor builds on mono for translating IL to Webassembly

Comment: But why would you even need .NET Core 3.0 for a client sided application? There aren't many APIs that could benefit from it (native span support doesnt matter much for client sided code, async sockets methods neither)

Comment: @Tseng I wanted to write server side + shared classes in NET Core 3.0 and add reference to them from the client

Comment: Yes, but why? You only need to target `netcorex.y` when you need apis that are only available there. If you don't need any .NET Core specific Api .NET Standard is pretty fine usage (and recommended for reusability, though not much to be reused on the client but shared libraries are reusable libraries)

Answer (score 8):

Client side Blazor runs on the Mono WASM runtime, and that only supports netstandard 2.0 ATM. The announcement of Blazor in Core refers to server side Blazor. The two are compatible code wise but the underlaying runtime technique is totally different.

Comment: I wanted to write server side + shared classes in NET Core 3.0 and add reference to them from the client, is that doable?

Comment: No. And there is not really a reason to to so. Shared libraries should be compiled against netstandard if you want to use them in client side blazor. netstandard 2.0 should be enough for any shared lib, net core 3.0 is not going to add anything useful that is usable on the client side anyway.

Comment: Yea, you wouldn't have much shared logic, models and stuff. Rest is either the ASP.NET Core server side (which runs on .NET Core and profits from it performance wise), but your shared libraries or business logic do not profit from targeting .NET Core 3.0. Its pretty rare that a library should target .NET Core at all (except for high performance APis only available on .NET Core, such as Async Socket extensions right now which support new Span/Memory types)

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` does not work on blazor because it requires .NET 3.0

As a result it requires a recompile manually every time I make a change which is slow when debugging.

Comment: Do you have to recompile every time? Or can you recompile manually once and then link to the newly created DLL (and it's debug symbols) for later debugging within the project utilizing it?